# Issue with URL pattern in Django with webmonkey tutorial

Tags: python, regex, django

I have been working my way through the Django webmonkey tutorial and am currently stuck in lesson 4 available here http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/Use_Templates_in_Django/.

My problem is with the blog detail template, whenever I click the link on my blog/list.html page to view the detail of the entry I get a Page not found (404).

This is exactly the error I see:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/2010/dec/17/welcome-my-blog/

Using the URLconf defined in djangoblog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 

^admin/(.*) 
^blog/ 
^tags/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$ 
The current URL, 2010/dec/17/welcome-my-blog/, didn't match any of these.
```

These are my url.py files as well as my models.py, I didn't post my admin, tag views or settings but I can if it would help.

**djangoblog\urls.py**

```
# This also imports the include function
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
(r'^blog/', include('djangoblog.blog.urls')),
(r'^tags/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$', 'djangoblog.tag_views.tag_detail'),
)
```

**djangoblog\blog\urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from djangoblog.blog.models import Entry
from tagging.views import tagged_object_list

info_dict = {
 'queryset': Entry.objects.filter(status=1),
 'date_field': 'pub_date',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
(r'(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$',    
 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, slug_field='slug',template_name='blog/detail.html')),
(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$',  
 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),   
(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/$',
 'archive_day',dict(info_dict,template_name='blog/list.html')),
(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/$','archive_month', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),
(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/$','archive_year', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),
(r'^$','archive_index', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),
)
```

**djangoblog\blog\models.py**.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.syndication.feeds import Feed
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
import markdown
from tagging.fields import TagField
from tagging.models import Tag

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique_for_date='pub_date',
        help_text='Automatically built from the title.'
    )

    body_html = models.TextField(blank=True)
    body_markdown = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published')
    tags = TagField()
    enable_comments = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    PUB_STATUS = (
        (0, 'Draft'),
        (1, 'Published'),
    )

    status = models.IntegerField(choices=PUB_STATUS, default=0)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pub_date',)
        get_latest_by = 'pub_date'
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/%s/%s/" %(self.pub_date.strftime("%Y/%b/%d").lower(), self.slug)

    def save(self):
         self.body_html = markdown.markdown(self.body_markdown, safe_mode = False)
         super(Entry, self).save()

    def get_previous_published(self):
        return self.get_previous_by_pub_date(status__exact=1)

    def get_next_published(self):
         return self.get_next_by_pub_date(status__exact=1)

    def get_tags(self):
         return Tag.objects.get_for_object(self)
```

If there are any other files that would help I can provide them. My file structure is laid out below:

**File Structure**

```
C:\Workspaces\python\djangoblog

urls.py
tag_views.py
settings.py
manage.py
djangoblog.db
admin.py
__init__.py

templates

 blog
  detail.html
  list.html

tags
    detail.html (empty)
    list.html (empty)

base.html

tagging

markdown

blog

 __init__.py
 admin.py
 models.py
 tests.py
 urls.py
 views.py
```

Edit: (from comment on Josh's answer)

404 at: blog/dec/17/welcome-my-blog/:

```
^admin/(.*) 
^blog/ (?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(? P<slug>[-w]+)/$ 
^blog/ ^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(? P<slug>[-w]+)/$ 
^blog/ ^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/$ 
^blog/ ^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/$ 
^blog/ ^(?P<year>d{4})/$ 
^blog/ 
^$ ^tags/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$ 
The current URL, blog/2010/dec/17/welcome-my-blog/, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that none of your URL patterns match the URL in the browser.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/2010/dec/17/welcome-my-blog/
```

Is the URL that you're trying to reach. I assume that is meant to be a blog entry, reachable at the URL `blog/`.

Your root URL patterns are the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),    
    (r'^blog/', include('djangoblog.blog.urls')),
    (r'^tags/(?P[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$', 'djangoblog.tag_views.tag_detail'),
)
```

Which means that none of them match your URL in the browser, since it does not start with either `admin` or `blog` or `tags`.

The following URL may fix your problem:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2010/dec/17/welcome-my-blog/
```

Notice the `/blog/` after the IP:Port. This will match the `blog/` entry in your root URL conf. Then it is up to your `djangoblog.blog.urls` file to handle the rest of the pattern, which it looks like it does.

```
(r'(?Pd{4})/(?P[a-z]{3})/(?Pw{1,2})/(?P[-w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, slug_field='slug',template_name='blog/detail.html'))
```

The above pattern looks for:
- 4 numbers (2010)
- then a /
- then 3 letters (dec)
- then a /
- then a word with 1 or 2 characters (17)
- then a /
- then a word (welcome-my-blog)

You should be fine by adding the `/blog/` after the IP:port.

Your Update:

```
^blog/ (?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(? P<slug>[-w]+)/$
```

The above URL is incorrect. You need to prepend it with a ^ as the other URLS.

Comment: I tried hacking my URL based on your recommendation so that it looks like yours, however I now get this 404:



    ^admin/(.*) 
    ^blog/ (?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?    P<slug>[-w]+)/$ 
    ^blog/ ^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?    P<slug>[-w]+)/$ 
    ^blog/ ^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/$ 
    ^blog/ ^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/$ 
    ^blog/ ^(?P<year>d{4})/$ 
    ^blog/ ^$ 
    ^tags/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$ 
    The current URL, blog/2010/dec/17/welcome-my-blog/, didn't match     any of these.

Answer (score 1):

For those that miss it as I did the major change is to change this - `P<year>d{4}` to this `P<year>\d{4}`. That is add the backslash. You may also wish to take a look at the `/$` at the end of the lines. These will force your urls to end in a "/".

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, Josh was right about the URL pattern missing the /blog. I updated my list template like so:

```
<p><a href="/blog{{object.get_absolute_url}}">read more</a></p>
```

That resolved the /blog error, after that I needed to modify my djangoblog\blog\urls.py like so:

**djangoblog\blog\urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',

(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\d\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, slug_field='slug',template_name='blog/detail.html')),

(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\d\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),

(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/$','archive_day',dict(info_dict,template_name='blog/list.html')),

(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/$','archive_month', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),

(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$','archive_year', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),

(r'^$','archive_index', dict(info_dict, template_name='blog/list.html')),

)
```

Once I made those two changes all of my URL's were fixed, I can't take credit for the urls.py fix as I found it on this site:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9650959

Hope this helps others in the future with this tutorial.